# Can't access my Windows 8 files on Ubuntu 14

Tags: dual-boot, mount

```
Error mounting /dev/sda8 at /media/shaswat/New Volume: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda8" "/media/shaswat/New Volume"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda8': Operation not permitted

The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I can't access any files on my Windows 8 machine on Ubuntu. I tried to shut down Windows once again and booting Ubuntu but it was of no help. Is it possible that I can access the files?

Comment: thanx for the edit muru but what about the solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda8` from the Terminal (`<Windows key>` -> Type "`Terminal`").

Also: When issuing the `mount` command from commandline make sure you run it as `sudo` (i.e.: *`sudo`*`mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda8" "/media/shaswat/New Volume"`).

Comment: i could only open one of the drives .the rest shows an error:

Comment: Error mounting /dev/sda7 at /media/shaswat/New Volume1: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda7" "/media/shaswat/New Volume1"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda7': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.